# Accessing Resolution Class with JIRA SOAP API

Tags: c#, api, soap, jira

When a user closes a JIRA issue, they select a "resolution class" such as "User error", "service request", etc.

Is it possible to look at this field's value using the SOAP API? I looked at the "resolution" fields of my issues, but they are always blank if the issue is open and "6" if closed (so "resolution class" must not be the same as "resolution").

Any information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So you want to get 'Resolution Class' field values. It is more than likely a custom field. So you will have to find id of this field by using getCustomFields() where RemoteField.getName() == "Resolution Class". And then you can call getCustomFieldValues() on your issue to get a value of the custom field.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for getResolutions method.

> RemoteResolution[] getResolutions(java.lang.String token)
>                                     throws RemotePermissionException,
>                                            RemoteAuthenticationException
>
> Returns an array of all the issue resolutions in JIRA.
>
> Parameters: token - the SOAP authentication token.
>
> Returns: an array of RemoteResolution objects
>
> Throws:
>   - RemotePermissionException - If the user is not permitted to perform this operation in this context.
>   - RemoteAuthenticationException - If the token is invalid or the SOAP session has timed out

Comment: Doesn't this give me the list of all possible Resolutions that a user can choose, rather than a listing of which items have which resolution? I would like to see what resolution was chosen for each issue.